# How to convert a JSON data back to protobuf message in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, protocol-buffers

I am using [protobuf-javascript](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript) library to compile proto files. Now, since it is not very well documented I am not able to find the way to convert my JSON response from the server back to the protobuf message.

Note: I am aware of protobuf.js library but I think it will not work with the proto compiled using protobuf-javascript library.

Please, any help will be appreciated.